# Search result orientation when using IE8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

I am from Israel and have Windows 7 64 bit professional english edition.

When I do a search using Google as the search provider in IE8 (search input windows at the top right corner) I get the results aligned to the right like so:

[image]

I want the results to be left aligned. Like when I do the same search in www.google.com:

[image]

Where do I find the setting for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like IE8 is detecting language settings and adjusting search results page formatting accordingly.  IE doesn't allow much control over the built-in search feature, but you could try changing its language settings to see if that helps.  Of course, that could cause different problems, but it's a worthwhile test: Tools > Internet Options > Languages, then select English as the language.  Another alternative would be to install the Google Toolbar, which gives you the same functionality as the built-in IE search box plus a lot more, and can be controlled to a much greater extent.

Answer (score 0):

I want to hazard a guess and say that there is a setting in your [Google Search settings](http://www.google.com/preferences) that may change the default language.  Google may be detecting that your searches are coming from Israel and it may be confused about language settings.  Is there a possibility that it is right-aligning the results to comply with the Hebrew language's written characteristics and the English text is getting dragged along with the right alignment?

Comment: It's a plausible explanation. I think the question is how to set the integrated search to work like the web one when he is logged in.

Comment: If he is logged-in, then all search results will be through his logged-in account because searching through the browser still brings you to a results page hosted by the search engine that is still accessing your login credentials cookie.  I think that @boot13 up above has a good suggestion as well, whereby there might be a conflict between search language settings and the actual browser language settings.  I hope the OP comes back and enlightens us on this!